# Why the result are different when I print in different places?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
    def sameDate(numPeople, numSame):
        possibleDates = range(366)
        birthdays = [0]*366
        for p in range(numPeople):
            birthDate = random.choice(possibleDates)
            birthdays[birthDate] += 1
        return max(birthdays) >= numSame

    def birthdayProb(numPeople, numSame, numTrials):
        numHits = 0
        for t in range(numTrials):
            if sameDate(numPeople, numSame):
                numHits += 1
        return numHits/numTrials

    print(birthdayProb(20,2,10000))
    random.seed(0)
    import math

    for numPeople in [20]:
        print(birthdayProb(numPeople, 2, 10000))
```

Result for first print :0.4143
Result for print inside for loop: 0.4035
why it is different when I print it inside a for loop?

Comment: It seems you have some indentation problems in the questions's code. Can you fix that please?

Comment: in addition to indentation problem, you are also calling random module. It will choose an item by random (by design). What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: The indentation is because of the editor of the stackoverflow now I have fixed it can you pls check it

Answer (score 1):

`birthdayProb` calls `sameDate`, which uses `random.choice()`. Therefore by design there will always be some variation of the results between two trials even with the same inputs.

If you want the trials to be repeatable but still have randomness, consider using `random.seed()` to set the seed before you call `birthdayProb` to make sure `random.choice()` always gives the same results each time.

Comment: I have used random.seed(0) and I got that two different answers

Comment: @manasaelenssen Did you use it before *each* call to `birthdayProb()`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the fault of for loop. This is due to using `random` in the code. `birthdayProb` function calls `sameDate` function. `sameDate` function is using `random.choice(possibleDates)` so the results will be slightly different each time it's called.